# Python InfluxDB Script

Tags: python, python-3.x, influxdb, influxdb-2, influxdb-python

I wanted to have the following script to document my speedtest data, however I get the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/pi/speedtest.py", line 35, in 
client.write_points(speed_data,)
AttributeError: 'InfluxDBClient' object has no attribute 'write_points'

What is the correct version of the script?

```
import re import subprocess from influxdb_client import InfluxDBClient
response = subprocess.Popen('/usr/bin/speedtest --accept-license --accept-gdpr', shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE).stdout.read().decode('utf-8')

ping = re.search('Latency:\s+(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)
download = re.search('Download:\s+(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)
upload = re.search('Upload:\s+(.*?)\s', response, re.MULTILINE)
jitter = re.search('Latency:.*?jitter:\s+(.*?)ms', response, re.MULTILINE)

ping = ping.group(1)
download = download.group(1)
upload = upload.group(1)
jitter = jitter.group(1)

speed_data = [
    {
        "measurement" : "internet_speed",
        "tags" : {
            "host": "Speedlink"
        },
        "fields" : {
            "download": float(download),
            "upload": float(upload),
            "ping": float(ping),
            "jitter": float(jitter)
        }
    }
]
bucket = "SpeedtestMonitor"

client = InfluxDBClient(url="http://localhost:8086", token="oM8PyToLgv-404hbNvH6BEIldKbSHy6h8WGYQYwSwkz1qrPnJ7brf5aW5sdsdsWtQO7GVou4XQRt51N1p-ozMWw==", org="Schmidt")

client.write_points(speed_data,)
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

You are using the InfluxDB2 Python library (influxdb_client.) The `InfluxDBClient` class does not have a `write_points` method. Instead you will need to get an instance of write_api and use its `write` method to perform your write.

So instead of `client.write_points(speed_data,)` try the following:

```
write_api = client.write_api(write_options=SYNCHRONOUS)
write_api.write(bucket=bucket, record=speed_data)
```

See [example](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/cloud/api-guide/client-libraries/python/) from InfluxDB docs and [write API documentation](https://influxdb-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#writeapi).